# NodeJS server blocked by certain wifi networks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

We have a NodeJS server running on an AWS EC2 instance to serve an iOS app. The server instance is running behind NGINX. We noticed that several public wifi networks are blocking the connection to the server, and we get no response from the server. This not only happens while using the actual mobile app, but also while attempting to get a server response using other clients (postman).

So far we've came across this on a university public wifi, train station and airport. So there are potentially quite a lot of users we are “losing” by this.
We assume this is due to a local firewall blocking unknown communication.

Does anybody know what are our options in such a case?
What do other apps do? Call each university and request to be added to the trusted connections seems kinda extreme...

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you using a non-standard port?

Comment: I don't think so, we are on port 3000..

Comment: Which is a non-standard port, my guess is the public network's firewall is blocking it. Try running a reverse proxy to port 80/443.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! We will try this over the weekend (we need to physically go there to check...). I'll update if it worked!

Comment: @BenFortune thank you! It worked. we have tried to change the port number in the past, and had an nginx listening on port 80 and 443, and then redirected the request to port 3000 via reverse proxy.  the problem was that the app itself specifically requested port 3000. once we changed that (the app now doesn't specify a port number), everything seems to work as expected.  Thanks! you are more then welcome to post this as an answer and I'll mark it if you want.